# Unity3d. Android. Prevent application switching

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Is there any way to prevent an android application from switching out?

I want to make an application for children, where you cannot switch to other applications, anyhow.

Comment: This would almost certainly require a custom image on the device. Application switching is an OS level feature, it's not something that can be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The OS control's the switching stack - not the application - this is by security design. In Android 5.0 you can "Pin applications" effectively blocking application switching.

There are a few applications which have somewhat complex (yet still easily circumventable) type of "lock screens", doing a similar task would achieve the same effect however you made need to write a native plugin. Ideally I would focus on the content of the app and push users towards using the Pin functionality.

[Google Support - Pin Apps](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6118421?hl=en)